# filtering on a range of values in a db column with sqlalchemy orm

Tags: postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, subset

I have a postgresql database and in one particular table, with many rows.  One column in this table, called data, is a float array, REAL[], and gets filled with an array of ~4500 elements.  I want to access this table through some query via SQLAlchemy and the ORM.

How do I select all rows in the table where a subset of this column satisfies some condition, e.g.contains a range of values?  Like I want to select all rows where the data contains values >= 10, or values between >=10 and <=20.

Can I do this with a straight session query like

```
rows = session.query(Table).filter(Table.data.(some conditional)).all()
```

where my conditional is something like "VALUES >= 10 and VALUES <= 20"?

Or do I need to define some special methods, or setup, when I'm defining my SQLAlchemy table class.  For example, I have my table set up as

```
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload' : True, 'schema' : 'testdb', 'extend_existing':True}

    data = deferred(Column(ARRAY(Float)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Table (pk={0})>'.format(self.pk)
```

Ideally I'd like to set it up so I can just do simple filtering in my session.query calls.  Is this possible?  I'm not super familiar with the ORM, so maybe it is?

I've had a look at the ARRAY Comparator sqlalchemy docs but those only seem to work on exact values.  My data is precise to 6 sigfigs, and I don't know the exact values ahead of time.

What's the best way to do this?  Thanks.

EDIT:

Based on the below comment, here is the code I'm using in attempting to select all rows (out of 1000) that have data (from 1 column) >= 1.0.  There should be 537 rows.

```
rows =  session.query(datadb.Table).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.0,operator=operators.le)).all()
```

This gives the correct subset number.  len(rows) = 537.  However, I don't understand the logic of with this operator, where to select data >=1.0 , I use the le operator? Also, along those same lines, there should be 234 rows that have data between the values >=1.0 and <1.0, but this statement fails to give the correct subset..

```
rows = session.query(datadb.Table).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.0,operator=operators.le)).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.2,operator=operators.ge)).all()
```

*** EDIT 2 ***

Here's an example of my database Table with a few rows.  pk is an integer, and data is a real[].

```
db datadb
schema Table 
pk      data
0       [0.0,0.0,0.5,0.3,1.3,1.9,0.3,0.0,0.0]
1       [0.1,0.0,1.0,0.7,1.1,1.5,1.2,0.3,1.4]
2       [0.0,0.6,0.4,0.3,1.6,1.7,0.4,1.3,0.0]
3       [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.4,1.0,1.1,1.2,0.9,0.0]
4       [0.0,0.0,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.7,0.3,0.1]
```

I have 5 rows, 4 of them have data with values >= 1.0, while just 2 have values in the range >= 1.0 and <= 1.2.  The query I would do to grab the rows is in the first case

```
rows = session.query(datadb.Table).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.0,operator=operators.le)).all()
```

This should return the 4 rows, at pk=0,1,2,3. This query does what I expect. The second case

```
rows = session.query(datadb.Table).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.0,operator=operators.le)).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.2,operator=operators.ge)).all()
```

and should return the 2 rows at pk=1,3.  However this query just returns the 4 rows from the first query. For the second query, I also tried

```
rows = session.query(datadb.Table).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.0,operator=operators.le),datadb.Table.data.any(1.2,operator=operators.ge)).all()
```

which also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please read documentation on [`ARRAY.Comparator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY.Comparator), according to which you should be able to do the following:

```
rows = (session.query(Table)
        .filter(Table.data.any(10, operator=operators.le))
        .filter(Table.data.any(20, operator=operators.ge)
).all()
```

**EDIT**:

```
# combined filter does not work,
# but applying one or the other is still useful as it reduces the result set
q = (session.query(MyTable)
     .filter(MyTable.data.any(1.0, operator=operators.le))
     # .filter(MyTable.data.any(1.2, operator=operators.ge))
     )

# filter in memory
items = [_row for _row in q.all()
         if any(1.0 <= item <= 1.2 for item in _row.data)]

for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Comment: So I tried this on a table with 1000 rows, of which 537 rows have data in the array >= 1.0.  I did rows=session.query(datadb.Table).filter(datadb.Table.data.any(1.0,operator=operator.ge)).all(), and it returned the same 1000 rows.

Comment: By *have data* you mean have *at least one item >= 1.0* or *all items  >= 1.0*? Also could you post the `SQL` statement executed?

Comment: Please see updated code, where was the typo, as for `data >= 1` one should use `operators.le`

Comment: To answer your questions, by 'have data' I mean the data array should have at least 1 element >=1.0.  I have editing my text to provide the example code I'm using.  I don't quite understand the logic behind selecting data >= 1.0 is used with the le operator?  And it doesn't work when I try to select rows with data >=1.0 and <= 1.2.

Comment: again, please see updated code: i never used this in real life, but it looks like operands are reversed: `(10, le)` means that `value >= 10` would be `TRUE`

Comment: I've tried your code but it only works with one condition.  When I try (1.0, le) and (1.2, ge) to select data in the range >=1.0, <= 1.2, it doesn't return the right number of rows.

Comment: I do not use array data types, so I cannot make a experience judgement here, but my test code works for your question. Could you provide an example of the `Table` row, its `data` column and the query which does not do what you expect?

Comment: I have updated my original post.  See Edit 2 for a example database table with columns and the two example queries.

Comment: Thank you. Now take a look at the second `filter` in isolation. It is easy to see that it does not filter any rows, because in every row there is at least one value that is `<=1.2`. And the fact that you combine it with another filter does not have any effect. This is to say that in this way you are not able to do a query like *give me rows where there is **any** value between 1 and 1.2*. If you need this type of filter, you should first select values matching criteria 1 and then check them against criteria 2.

Comment: Yeah I was coming to that conclusion myself playing around with the different filters.  It doesn't make sense logically though.  Two filters are supposed to be joined by an AND.  So logically it should read as >=1.0 AND <=1.2, but instead it seems to be more like an OR join.  I'll keep playing around with it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: It doesn't even seem like this kind of query works in regular SQL.  Here is the postgresql query that also does not work:  "select count(s.pk) from db.Spaxel as s where(1.0 <= any(s.flux) and 1.2 >= any(s.flux));" I also tried building two queries as you suggest, where I do the >=1.0 selection first and from those results try to do the 2nd query, and that also does not work.

Comment: I do not know much about `ARRAY` type, but if you can select only those items from array which fit the criteria, and then apply the other filter, you should be able to achieve what you desire. Having said that, i could not find how to do that.
Another question: do you really need to do this on a large set of data? because if not, load these into python (SA) and do the filter there.

Comment: Yeah I can't get it to work either and I think it should.  I've tried it in memory as well, but I will end up having millions of rows and I don't think I want to try to read all of them into python to perform the filtering.